# While loop to confirm user input

Tags: c#, parsing, while-loop, try-catch

I am stuck on a c# issue where I cant get the while loop to end.

userValue is a string that is input earlier on in the program.

The string is formatted in DateTime, and the new input need to match the original userValue. I.E *Confirming* the the users original birth date.

I used a try / catch to determine if the input can be parsed to DateTime.

Currently it is just a constant loop, i'm trying to have the loop stop once the users birth date is verified.

```
string userValueTwo;

int stop = 0;
while (stop != 0)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please verify your birth date");
    userValueTwo = Console.ReadLine();

     try
     {
        DateTime birthdayTwo = DateTime.Parse(userValueTwo);
     }
     catch
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid format.");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

     if (userValueTwo == userValue)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Birth date confirmed.");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your birthday did not match our records. Please try again");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: You never increment `stop` or call `break` so it *can't* exit the loop.

Comment: Consider using `DateTime.TryParse` instead of using an Exception to capture the failure of parsing.

Comment: On the other hand... can it even enter the loop? `stop = 0;` then `stop != 0` should always result in false if there's nothing in between.

Comment: @Aaron As Dave pointed out, and as you see in Kyriacross's answer, you are in direct control of when (or if ever) a while loop ends. You can either terminate it "early" with the `break;` command or let the while loop know that the condition has been met to terminate. 

In general, `while (condition==true) { this.do(something); }` loops continue forever until your condition becomes false. That won't happen arbitrarily; you need to set that condition to false, somehow.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use the **break** statement after the date is confirmed, although it is not reccommended.

Since you have already implemented a stop condition, just set stop to 1 after the date is confirmed and the while loop will not continue running.

Here's a better solution using a boolean:

```
bool stop = false;
while (!stop)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please verify your birth date");
    userValueTwo = Console.ReadLine();

     try
     {
        DateTime birthdayTwo = DateTime.Parse(userValueTwo);
     }
     catch
     {
         Console.WriteLine("You did not enter a valid format.");
         Console.ReadLine();
     }

     if (userValueTwo == userValue)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Birth date confirmed.");
         Console.ReadLine();
         stop = true;
     }

    else 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Your birthday did not match our records. Please try again");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Bingo! I was just going to suggest that someone throw a code example in their answer...

Comment: I am trying it like this and getting the error on the (!stop). "Use of unassigned local variable stop"

Comment: Ah, just set it so false. Editing answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 0):

After it's confirmed, use **break;** in the line of code following.

Answer (score 0):

You have entered an infinite loop. Infinite loops typically when a user has not fulfilled one or more requirements for the code to "hop" on back out of the loop To exit a loop once a objective is fulfilled, use "break;", to escape out of that current loop. In cases where a loop is nested, this might need to happen more than once

Answer (score 0):

You never change the value of `stop`.