# I want to change/add a parameter in a loop and keep the loop running until the corrent temperature is entered

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project in where you enter a temperature for a sauna and if you enter a to low temperature it will tell you to increase the temperature until you get it high enough but I need it to continuously ask for a higher temperature until you get a high enough temperature without you having to restart the program so I need to be able to change the temperature in the loop and then write out the temperature outside the loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
    String tempInput = Console.ReadLine();
    Int32 tempF = Convert.ToInt32(tempInput);
    Int32 tempC = (tempF - 32) * 5 / 9;
    Int32 tempCInDoLoop = 0;

    Console.WriteLine("Temperature is to low, enter a higher temperature");

    if (tempC < 73 && tempCInDoLoop < 73)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter higher temperature");
        String tempInputInDoLoop = Console.ReadLine();
        Int32 tempFInDoLoop = Convert.ToInt32(tempInputInDoLoop);
        Int32 tempCInDoLoop = (tempFInDoLoop - 32) * 5 / 9;
    }
    //Console.WriteLine(tempFInDoLoop);
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [While loop to confirm user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111978/while-loop-to-confirm-user-input), [loop until Console.ReadLine = 'y' or 'n'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41609470/8967612), [How to loop user input until the datatype of the input is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4996793/8967612), and many others.

Comment: There is no loop here, that may be your problem

Comment: "i need to be able to change the temperature in the loop"...ok so what is stopping you from creating a loop then? It's unclear what the problem is. What have you tried? What went wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to give you something that you can learn from:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter temperature");
    
    double temperatureC = double.NaN;

    while (double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out temperatureC) && temperatureC < 73.0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureC}°C is to low, enter a higher temperature");
    }
    
    double temperatureF = temperatureC * 9.0 / 5.0 + 32.0;

    Console.WriteLine($"{temperatureC}°C, {temperatureF}°F");
}
```

See if that does what you need.

Comment: That worked for a bit, but i need to add a max temperature too now, i've tried to copy the code and change the operands but i get the error code CS0128 "A local variable of function nemed 'temperatureC' is already defined in this scope".
Do you know how to fix this? Also the secound while loop wont write out the WriteLine when the secound loop is active

Comment: You should only declare variables once. If you have a min and a max temperature then you have two variables and you should declare each once.

Comment: I also don't understand what you mean by "Also the secound while loop wont write out the WriteLine when the secound loop is active". You might need to provide me with the code you've written.