# How to loop a Console.ReadLine to the infinite?

Tags: c#, loops, math, calculator, infinite

Hello i'm trying to create a calculator game but it loops only 2 times and (idk why)not til the user finds the result with input. And i'll later see how to make a random generator of numbers instead of writing them by myself in the code. Ty for helping.

Yassine

```
using System;

namespace G
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Calcul(2, 2);
        }
        static void Calcul(int nombre1, int nombre2)
        {

            int result = nombre1 + nombre2;
            
            Console.WriteLine("Combien font " + nombre1 + " + " + nombre2);

            int supposed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            if(result != supposed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again!");
                supposed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
              
            }
            else 
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Correct!");
            }



        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "it loops only 2 times" - No it doesn't... do you know how to use *actual* loops?

Comment: (I tried the while loop but i didn't found how to deal with it.)

Comment: What troubles are you having with a `while` loop? They are pretty basic features. Perhaps start out with a simple tutorial like [this one](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-while-loop)?

Comment: `while(true) { // put code inside loop here }`

Comment: Hint: `do{/* code here */}while(/* condition */);`

Comment: Change the `if` to `while (result != supposed)` if you want to loop until they get the correct answer.

Comment: `while (result != supposed)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Try again!");
                supposed = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }`

This is what i did but, how to put a "Correct!" message when the while is at his end?

Comment: Duplicate of [While loop to confirm user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111978/while-loop-to-confirm-user-input), [loop until Console.ReadLine = 'y' or 'n'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41609470/8967612), [How to loop user input until the datatype of the input is correct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4996793/8967612), and many others.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your `if` statement to a `while` loop whose condition is that the input does not match the result. We can also use `int.TryParse` with `Console.ReadLine` to handle cases where the user doesn't enter a valid number. This works by taking an `out` parameter that gets set to the parsed value if it's successful, and it returns a `bool` that indicates success. Perfect for a loop condition!

Then you can put the "success" message *after* the body of the `while` loop (because the only way to exit the loop is to get the correct answer). It would look something like:

```
static void Calcul(int nombre1, int nombre2)
{
    int result = nombre1 + nombre2;
    int input;

    Console.Write($"Combien font {nombre1} + {nombre2} = ");

    while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input) || input != result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Incorrect, please try again.");
        Console.Write($"Combien font {nombre1} + {nombre2} = ");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Correct! Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```